# How to Pass Report Parameter as if it were a Query Parameter?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2017

I am trying to make a report that allows a user to input an ID and then check this ID against several payee tables to see if the value already exists. The code requires an input and then displays a value of 1 if the code already exists and a 0 if the code is available for use. This works in the SQL code when setting the ID as a query parameter, but does not appear to work when creating an SSRS report and passing a report parameter through; the report displays no data.

I have tried adding a tablix column to display the parameter for validation. This field remains blank when attempting to pass a report parameter, but does properly display when hardcoding the query parameter.

```
DECLARE @id varchar(8)

SELECT @id,
    CASE
        WHEN @id IN (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM payee_1
                    )
        THEN 1
        WHEN @id IN (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM payee_2
                    )
        THEN 1
        WHEN @id IN (
                    SELECT id
                    FROM payee_3
                    )
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END as validation
```

The SQL query produces the results I would like to see in the SSRS report. It simply shows the input ID and a 1 if not available (or a 0 if available). When input into SSRS, the report parameter never passes through as if it were a query parameter and my report ends up being blank.

Answer (score 1):

When your report is open for edit (Visual Studio), in the "Report Data" panel (docked on the left, by default), expand "Datasets". Right-click your Dataset and choose "Dataset Properties".

[image: Report Data panel in Visual Studio]

In the "Dataset Properties" window, on the left, click "Parameters". The parameters shown are populated from your query. If you have a parameterized query, then this will give you the option to bind your query parameters ("Parameter Value") to your report parameters, or set up other defaults or formulas, etc.

[image: Dataset Properties window in Visual Studio]

Comment: The parameter value has been set and associated in SSRS. I had actually tried setting this association prior to your comment, but it still did not pass through properly. https://imgur.com/ZbbwPXR                                                https://imgur.com/sA1mBmf

Comment: Is it working now?  If not, could you give a little more explanation or a screen shot or something?  Maybe show your SQL query.

Comment: It is not working. I have attached some screen grabs. What I would anticipate to happen in the report is: the user inputs the lookup code, the validation should show 1 if the code exists in any of the payee tables, and the id should show the code passed through by the user. I plan on cleaning up the form once functionality is in place